# Typecasting from basic data type to user defined type

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, operator-overloading

Is it possible to type cast basic data type to class type by overloading conversion operator
or do I have to overload = operator in c++

just to be clear

```
classname obj;
float f=obj;
```

is overloading typecasting operator from class to float and

```
float f;
classname obj=f;
```

is typecasting from float to class.So my question basically is for latter code to be correct is it possible by overloading typecasting or should I use overloading = operator.

I know overloading = works but I just wanted to know if it's possible to overload typecasting operator in that way.

Comment: That's implicit conversion. Casting is explicit conversion, like `static_cast<float>(obj)`or `(classname) f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> classname obj;
> float f=obj;
> ```

is possible if `classname` has an `operator float()`, for example

```
class classname
{
     public:
         classname() : value(0.0f) {};
         operator float() const {return value;};
     private:
         float value;
};
```

while

> ```
> float f;
> classname obj=f;
> ```

is possible if `classname` has a converting constructor, such as

```
class classname
{
     public:
         classname(float v) : value(x) {};
     private:
         float value;
};
```

If you want to assign an existing object to a `float` such as

```
float x;
classname f;
f = x;
```

requires an assignment operator.

```
class classname
{
     public:
         classname() : value(0.0f) {};
         classname &operator=(float v) {value = v; return *this;}
     private:
         float value;
};
```

Obviously, if you want to construct or assign an object using a `float`, the class has to have both a relevant constructor AND a relevant assignment operator.

Comment: So what I asked was that if we could explicitly cast float to classname

Comment: You may have thought you asked about explicit casting.   Your post doesn't read that way to me.   In any event, if a class supports an appropriate conversion constructor then an explicit cast using `static_cast` uses that.   You could use another cast to force a conversion without such a constructor, but any use of the resultant object often lands you in the realm of undefined behaviour.    Hence the common advice - don't use an explicit cast (C-style or C++ `xxx_cast`) unless you know exactly what the intended effect is.  And, often, it is better to find an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

`classname obj=f;` is initialization, then you can provide a [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) taking `float` to support constructing `classname` from `float`.

e.g.

```
class classname {
public:
    classname(float) { ... }
    ...
};
```